# What can be said about $z_1$ or $z_2$ if $z_1 z_2=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose that $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ are complex numbers. What can be said about $z_{1}$ or $z_{2}$ if $z_{1}z_{2}=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and that $z_1 z_2 = 0$. Now if $z_1 \neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{z_1} \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus $0 = \frac{1}{z_1}\cdot 0 = \frac{1}{z_1}(z_1 z_2) = (\frac{1}{z_1}z_1) z_2 = 1 \cdot z_2 = z_2$ and hence $z_2 = 0$. So either $z_1 = 0$ or $z_2 = 0$ (or both).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $0=|0|=|z_1 z_2 | = |z_1| |z_2|,$ and because $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$ are both real numbers, either $|z_1|=0$ or $|z_2|=0$.

But then either $z_1=0$ or $z_2=0.$

Comment: You reduced a problem concerning $\mathbb C$ to a problem concerning $\mathbb R$. It might still be a problem for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If $z_{1}z_{2}=0$ then we have $z_1=0$ or $z_2=0$.

Comment: @Havalhassan It's a property of rings.

Comment: $\mathbb C$ is a field and fields are zero-divisor free.

Comment: @rubik it is a property if integral domains, or fields, not of rings.

Comment: @Improve You're right. It would have been better to say "of some rings", i.e. integral domains.